# Apache Beam / Flink ExceptionInChainedStubException

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

I am using Apache Beam 2.0.0 and the FlinkRunner (scala 2.10) of the same version.  I am testing against an in-process Flink master (default configuration) with the FlinkRunner dependency apparently bringing in Flink 1.2.1 at runtime (looking at MVN dependency tree).

What is the best way to figure out what actually went wrong when there are "User exceptions"?  This is not a question about what I did wrong this time; but rather how to tell - in general- how to get more info out of either Beam or Flink.  Here is  stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Pipeline execution failed
at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkRunner.run(FlinkRunner.java:122)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:295)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:281)
at com.mapfit.flow.data.environment.MFEnvironment.run(MFEnvironment.java:70)
at com.mapfit.flow.main.Scratch.main(Scratch.java:35)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:910)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(JobManager.scala:853)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(JobManager.scala:853)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.chaining.ExceptionInChainedStubException
at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:36)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$auxiliary$PCieS8xh.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:197)
at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:158)
at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.metrics.DoFnRunnerWithMetricsUpdate.processElement(DoFnRunnerWithMetricsUpdate.java:65)
at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.functions.FlinkDoFnFunction.mapPartition(FlinkDoFnFunction.java:118)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.MapPartitionDriver.run(MapPartitionDriver.java:103)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.run(BatchTask.java:490)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.invoke(BatchTask.java:355)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:665)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.chaining.ExceptionInChainedStubException
at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.chaining.ChainedFlatMapDriver.collect(ChainedFlatMapDriver.java:82)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.metrics.CountingCollector.collect(CountingCollector.java:35)
at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.functions.FlinkDoFnFunction$MultiDoFnOutputManager.output(FlinkDoFnFunction.java:165)
at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:355)
at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:629)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:122)
```

Notice the complete lack of anything related to code I wrote (other than my call to pipeline.run()).

I downloaded the source code for each of my linked jars, and I stepped into the `ChainedFlatMapDriver` which threw an exception on line 82, and eventually ended up looking at an EOFException generated by a call in Java object serialization (my values use default Coder).  I thought I wan onto something, but it appears that the cause of the EOFException is in `SimpleCollectingOutputView` line 79, which is thrown a lot, and often swallowed as what appears to be routine execution for Flink.

Any pointers from anyone who knows how to get Flink to disclose failure information?

Found more information after debugging:

```
Just found more info after walking through more Flink code in the debugger: java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.LocalBufferPool.requestBuffer(LocalBufferPool.java:168)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.LocalBufferPool.requestBufferBlocking(LocalBufferPool.java:138)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.writer.RecordWriter.sendToTarget(RecordWriter.java:131)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.writer.RecordWriter.emit(RecordWriter.java:88)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.shipping.OutputCollector.collect(OutputCollector.java:65)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.metrics.CountingCollector.collect(CountingCollector.java:35)
at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.functions.FlinkMultiOutputPruningFunction.flatMap(FlinkMultiOutputPruningFunction.java:46)
at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.functions.FlinkMultiOutputPruningFunction.flatMap(FlinkMultiOutputPruningFunction.java:30)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.chaining.ChainedFlatMapDriver.collect(ChainedFlatMapDriver.java:80)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.metrics.CountingCollector.collect(CountingCollector.java:35)
at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.functions.FlinkDoFnFunction$MultiDoFnOutputManager.output(FlinkDoFnFunction.java:165)
at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:355)
at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:629)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:122)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$auxiliary$vuuNRtio.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:197)
at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:158)
at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.metrics.DoFnRunnerWithMetricsUpdate.processElement(DoFnRunnerWithMetricsUpdate.java:65)
at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.translation.functions.FlinkDoFnFunction.mapPartition(FlinkDoFnFunction.java:118)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.MapPartitionDriver.run(MapPartitionDriver.java:103)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.run(BatchTask.java:490)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.invoke(BatchTask.java:355)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:665)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these two links : 
[EOFException related to memory segments during run of Beam pipeline on Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45934929/eofexception-related-to-memory-segments-during-run-of-beam-pipeline-on-flink)

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2831

I used to see similar exceptions while running beam on flinkrunner on yarn. Proposed coder in the page of the issue helped.

Apart from that I suggest to use loggers extensively until your pipeline runs smoothly. In yarn logs can be retrieved with yarn logs command. Do not know about your case (in-process Flink master) but you should be able to write some logs I assume...

Comment: I will mark this as the accepted answer, since I opened this case (a half a month before the links you mentioned existed), as usual no one could help; and then worked around the issue in basically the same way as mentioned in the link, and then neglected this ticket :)