# EOFException related to memory segments during run of Beam pipeline on Flink

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

I'm trying to run an Apache Beam pipeline on Flink on our test cluster. It has been failing with an `EOFException` at [`org.apache.flink.runtime.io.disk.SimpleCollectingOutputView:79`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.2.1/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/io/disk/SimpleCollectingOutputView.java#L79) during the encoding of an object through serialisation. I haven't been able to reproduce the error locally, yet. You can find [the entire job log here](https://pastebin.com/raw/HppzqhyN). Some values have been replaced with fake data.

The command used to run the pipeline:

```
bin/flink run \
     -m yarn-cluster                                         \
     --yarncontainer                 1                       \
     --yarnslots                     4                       \
     --yarnjobManagerMemory          2000                    \
     --yarntaskManagerMemory         2000                    \
     --yarnname "EBI"        \
     pipeline.jar               \
     --runner=FlinkRunner \
     --zookeeperQuorum=hdp-master-001.fake.org:2181
```

While I think it's not related, the object-to-be-serialised is serialisable and has had both an implicit and an explicit coder, but this doesn't affect the situation.

What might be causing this situation and what can I do to address it?

---

*For now, increasing the heap memory of the managers to somewhere between 4 and 8GiB seems to prevent the exception. Still unsure if this is supposed to be normal Flink behaviour (shouldn't it spill to disk?). Doesn't seem like a solution that would scale.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EOFException` is thrown because Flink ran out of memory buffers. Flink expects an `EOFException` as a notification to start to write data to disk.

This problem is caused by Beam's `SerializableCoder` wraps the `EOFException` in a `CoderException`. Hence, Flink does not catch the expected `EOFException` and fails.

The problem can be solved by using a custom coder that does not wrap the `EOFException` but forwards it.

Comment: This problem has been reported to the Beam team and a solution may be provided in a future release. To follow progress on this, subscribe to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2831